# Re-target .NET Core to net471, net 472

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.1

My .Netcore 2.0 project can target `net471`.
But when I upgraded to .NET 2.1, I can't retarget `net471` or `net472`

Can I retarget in the latest version of .the NET core?

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible with net471 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
```

and

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
```

Comment: In the most of cases, this is because the version of .NET Core SDK or Nuget is out of date. So try to update the version of Nuget

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is the new one, come with Asp.net core 2.1

Comment: What the message said. `AspNetCore.App` is a metapackage targeting .net core 2.1. It is used so we dont have to reference dozens of smaller ASP.NET Core assemblies. If you want to retarget to .NET Framework you have to REMOVE `AspNetCore.App` and add the single packages which you need, i.e. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: Easiest way to do is, create a new empty ASP.NET Core project which targets .NET Framework 4.7.2, then copy the package references from it and replace the `.AspNetCore.All` (or `.AspNetCore.All`) package with these references as well as change the target platform in the csproj

Comment: Thanks, @Tseng your solution works fine.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` packages only work with the `netcoreapp2.0` or `netcoreapp2.1` version.

Wanting to target .NET Framework i.e. `net471, net472`, you have to remove these packages and manually add the references.

In my case, I removed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and added references as below.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.1" />
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I am targeting net48 and could not get it to work.
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio I was given the impression that the reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App would work.

Answer (score 1):

Hung Quach's answer is right 99% right. However I found it was missing two packages. So below is the full .csproj including the two missing project refs:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```